# how to hide text data in wav file via hex editor

Tags: audio, hide, steganography

I am able to embed text data into wav audio file using StegHide

> steghide embed -cf filename.wav -ef filename.txt

and for extracting:

> steghide extract -sf filename.wav

but with this I am only able to hide my text document into an audio file, I need something else: ho tide the text itself (not the text document) in wav audio file using Hex Editor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A text document is pretty much just text, so the program already does for you what you want. Whether you represent the letters internally as bytes or ascii codes from 0 to 255, the process is the same. And it sounds like if you were to do it with a hex editor, it'd be a manual process? What is it exactly that you're trying to do? It doesn't sound awful different from what steghide already does for you, so if you study the code and understand how it works, you can adapt it to your preferences.

Comment: @Reti43 - that is correct, I want to 'hide' text manually in the wav file code which is represented via hex editor. maybe there are some manuals, or examples of doing it?

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on the internet. You can start by looking into least significant bit (or lsb) steganography. However, SO concerns itself with programming question, not with providing off-site material or broad question that have open-ended answers.